# Delete login entry in terminal registry

Tags: macos, terminal, windows-registry, login

I opened terminal and typed "last username" (my username) and I see the list of all the logins with date and time.

Is it possible to delete an entry? One person has the password and I want to know if it's possible the person logged in the computer and erased his tracks.

Thank you!!!!

Comment: Is your question about MacOS or Windows? Please [edit] your question to use the appropriate tags.

Comment: I had added macos in the tags

Comment: So why is this tagged as windows registry if your question is about MacOS?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, and might sound rude (apologies in that case, that's not my intent)... but maybe you should reconsider sharing your password with someone you don't fully trust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to remove your last login and its very simple

You can check out this [link](https://osxdaily.com/2010/06/22/remove-the-last-login-message-from-the-terminal/) which tells you how to do so.
You just have to make a *.hushlogin* file in */Users/NAME/.hushlogin* if you are a *root user*, and remove it after you are done with your login.

Additionally:

1. If you leave your laptop on sleep you can check your [logs](https://osxdaily.com/2012/02/25/how-to-tell-if-someone-was-using-mac/)
2. if you're really paranoid you can do this to [further prevent/log an attackers movements](https://www.wired.com/2016/08/tell-roommate-using-computer/)